# running python StringIO files

Tags: python, file, memory, buffer, stringio

I want to run a memfile done with StringIO. Is there any possibility for doing it? something like this:

```py
import StringIO

memfile = StringIO.StringIO()
memfile.write("print 'hello world'")

#with diskfiles I would do:
#os.system('python memfile') ?
#subprocess.Popen('memfile', shell=True)
memfile.close()
```

Comment: And what would the memory file contain to run? Python code, bash scripts, binary executables?

Comment: The example content written to the `memfile` looks like Python code to me

Comment: I solved it with exec memfile.getvalue() and it works with multiline file, for example memfile content "a = 0\nb=1\nprint a+b" thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
eval(memfile.open().read())
```

EDIT:

It turns out `exec` is needed, as `eval` accepts expressions only:

```
exec memfile
```

Comment: it don't work because print is a statement not an expresion, but you gave me a clue, exec memfile.getvalue() works, thanks!